# CSS div class not recognized

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm having this problem with CSS: I'm using the form group like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group"> <!-- or "form-group-test"-->
        <label class="col-xs-4 plate-control-label">...
```

the `plate-control-label` is defined by myself in the CSS file like this:

```
.form-horizontal .plate-control-label {...}
```

and it works normally; but when I tried to do similar things to div:

```
.form-horizontal .form-group-test {...}
```

then it is not recognized. I have to define it like this:

```
.form-horizontal .form-group {...}
```

In this way it works, but as form-group is a pre-defined element, I don't want to change it. Why is this?

**EDIT:** Sorry just now missed the ". I'm not copying the code directly.

**EDIT2**: Okay I tried in fiddle and it works, but in my own code it's still not okay. The elements are contained inside these divs:

```
<div class="panel-body panel-container" style="overflow: auto">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div style="float: left; width: 35%">
```

Could this cause the problem? Thank you all for the previous reminders and advice.

Comment: Simple case of a missed `"`

Comment: can you put your code that isn't working into something like a JSfiddle, so we can see it? It should work fine.

Comment: Is it a specificity problem maybe? Have you tried forcing with !important just to see if your styling is being overridden?

Comment: @brad miller yes !important has been tried alr, but not working.

Comment: This fiddle seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/vrx5aa7e/

Comment: Well I recreated everything you put in the question in a fiddle and it worked just fine. Look for unclosed CSS statements. Final fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vrx5aa7e/4/

Answer (score 4):

you're not closing the class here:

```
<label class="col-xs-4 plate-control-label>
```

should be like this

```
<label class="col-xs-4 plate-control-label">
```

**UPDATE** based on your updated question

Forgetting the typo mentioned above.

Regarding to this:

> and it works normally; but when I tried to do similar things to div:
>
> `.form-horizontal .form-group-test {...}`

won't work because you don't have a class in your HTML named `.form-group-test`,

so in order to make that line to work you need to change your HTML to this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group-test"> 
        <label class="col-xs-4 plate-control-label">
```

if you want to use `form-group` due to be a predefined element, you use like this:

**CSS:**

`.form-horizontal .form-group` -- to target `.form-group`

`.form-horizontal .form-group-test .plate-control-label` --  to target `plate-control-label`

**HTML:**

```
 <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <label class="col-xs-4 plate-control-label">
```

Comment: Sorry but I mean I changed the class to form-group-test (the comment in the html file) and it doesn't work. So I have to rename it to form-group in the CSS file, which is not so ideal because this is a pre-defined element and I don't want to change it.

Comment: so use the `form-group`, no?

Comment: Yes currently I'm using form-group, but as I said, it's a pre-defined element so I don't want to change it. I just want to know why if I define a new one like form-group-test it won't work.

Comment: @Richards if the fiddle works, show us a link of your site

Comment: Sorry I'm working on a local machine and the whole site is still under development. The company won't release it shortly. Maybe I'll stick to form-group first cos it's not a big project and I don't think I'll use form-group again. Anyway thank you for the help! I know it's not actually solving the problem, but sigh...